# Convert varchar to date in sql loader

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-loader

I have loaded the date field with dates and type is varchar.

How to convert date field(varchar) to date field(date) in oracle express/sql loader while displaying the fields?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what you are asking.  Are you asking how to change the data type of a column in a permanent table?  How to use SQL*Loader to load data into a `DATE` column in a table?  How to change an external table definition from `VARCHAR2` to `DATE`?  Or something else?

Comment: I have already loaded with type varchar. Now for comparing with other databases , i need to convert the datatype to DATE in order to be compatible with the fields of other databases

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the data type of a column in a permanent table from `VARCHAR2` to `DATE` when it has data.

You can, however, add a new column

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
  ADD( new_date_column DATE );
```

move the data over

```
UPDATE table_name
   SET new_date_column = to_date( old_varchar2_column, format_mask );
```

drop the old column

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
  DROP COLUMN old_varchar2_column;
```

and then rename the new column to the old column name

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
  RENAME COLUMN new_date_column TO old_column_name
```

Of course, once you do this, you'll need to change your SQL*Loader script to convert the data to a `DATE` if you ever want to load into this table again.

Comment: I dont want to change any characteristics of columns, but just wanted to display as date. Whether that is possible? Using with any function like cast...?

Comment: @RRR - I'm still confused about exactly what you're asking.  Perhaps you just want to call the `to_date` function on the column as part of your comparison (though that will be rather slow)?